# Change bottom border styling on mat-autocomplete

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, angular-material

I went through several links but I can't find a solution. Here is the [demo code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-autocomplete-eg-zk7nmh?file=app%2Fautocomplete-filter-example.scss).

I want to remove the purple color and replace it with red, but I am unable to do that. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to overwrite class like this:

```
.mat-form-field.mat-focused {        
    .mat-form-field-ripple {
        background-color: red;
    }
}
```

[The complete stackblitz example can be seen here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-autocomplete-eg-pzrcsm?file=app%2Fautocomplete-filter-example.scss)

Answer (score 1):

Try below styling:

```
autocomplete-filter-example {
  input[type="text"] {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  }
  input[type="text"]:focus {
    border-bottom: 1px solid red !important;
  }
  .mat-form-field-underline {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

[Demo code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-autocomplete-eg-rjd3dg?file=app%2Fautocomplete-filter-example.scss)